# Place custom block on particular content type pages and home page

Tags: blocks

I have a custom block which I want to place on all the pages of one content type AND on the home page. The home page is a custom twig file that pulls in the region where the block is placed. Right now I have the custom block limited to the content type I want but of course that precludes being able to put it on the home page. Is there an elegant way to get it in both places? I'm also using Twig Tweak if that will help.

(Worst case I'll duplicate the block content and put it right into the twig file but I'm trying to avoid that.)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Block Visibilty Group-module can solve you problem?

Comment: @BerryDingle That did the trick! I was able to specify the two conditions (particular content type and front page) and say the block should display when one or the other is satisfied. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two instances of the block on the manage blocks page. One instance can be limited to the content types on which you want it shown, and the other instance can be limited by path, which you will then set to `<front>`.